# cal_days_in_month () function is not working

Tags: php

This `cal_days_in_month()`  is not working in PHP version 5.2.11

```
$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0,$month,$year);
```

Comment: `echo $month; echo $year;` Report back.

Comment: Not sure, but try to change the 0 to `CAL_GREGORIAN` Also http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php See if your inputs is correct.

Comment: What's not working exactly? empty result, error message..?

Comment: @Raj Kumar: By default the function works as far as we all know. However, in your case it's not known what `$month` and `$year` is, so we can't help you.

Comment: Try to be more specific with your question. What is not working? What is the input? What is the output? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 34):

Try

```
date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
```

And I found in internet that it require PHP to compile with calender support.

"recompile php with the "--enable-calendar" option."

Comment: Great Thanks For this date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));         I Got my Answer

Comment: This is the best answer I've found (in case someone doesn't want to recompile php)

Comment: Do we need to move to any directory and the command for "recompile php with the "--enable-calendar" option." , Will I need to download anything.. from somewhere ? I came upto https://www.php.net/manual/en/calendar.installation.php, and am unsure how to move on.

Comment: Sweet, how can i not think of this.

Answer (score 10):

Having the same problem in a docker container (based on image `php:7.4-apache-buster`) adding following line in `Dockerfile` solved the problem:

`RUN docker-php-ext-install calendar`

Comment: You are a legend!  This answer is what I needed to get my dev container up and running. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found it on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php
You can use this without recompile PHP
Cre: David Bindel

```
function days_in_month($month, $year)
{
// calculate number of days in a month
return $month == 2 ? ($year % 4 ? 28 : ($year % 100 ? 29 : ($year % 400 ? 28 : 29))) : (($month - 1) % 7 % 2 ? 30 : 31);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to provide calendar :

```
int cal_days_in_month ( int $calendar , int $month , int $year )
```

like:

```
$month_length = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
```

you maybe confusing it with `cal_info ([ int $calendar = -1 ] )`
which takes a representation of the calendar :

```
0 or CAL_GREGORIAN - Gregorian Calendar
1 or CAL_JULIAN - Julian Calendar
2 or CAL_JEWISH - Jewish Calendar
3 or CAL_FRENCH - French Revolutionary Calendar
```

Answer (score -3):

Because syntax is :

```
$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(CALENDAR,$month,$year);
```

like this :

```
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 2, 2012);
```